# generate a random series from array

Tags: reactjs

I want to generate random order of record data. Is there any clear and clever way with React hooks?

For example I have data:

```
let data = [
{user: user1, points: 5},
{user: user2, points: 6},
{user: user3, points: 8},
{user: user4, points: 1}
];
```

And with some random function I want to get some random order:

```
OUTPUT:

{user: user3, points: 8},
{user: user2, points: 6},
{user: user4, points: 1},
{user: user1, points: 5}
```

I don´t want to choose only one random element, but I want to get all elements from the data, but only in random order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)

Comment: Yes, Fisher-Yates algorithms works! :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing that is using the sort method with random value:

```
data.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this, but after the third click on the button (random draw), I got the same sorted data as first. But Fisher-Yates algorithm works.